# Using firefox only CSS to round corners of elements?

Tags: css, firefox, rounded-corners

I just noticed that Stack Overflow employs Firefox only CSS to round the corners of the user badges on the front page. It's an interesting idea but what would be the pitfalls and advantages of using Firefox only CSS (aside from the blatantly obvious ones)?

```
-moz-border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
```

Above: The CSS used to round corners on the Stack Overflow front page.

Comment: It appears to also apply to webkit...

Comment: And you have to remember that those of us with just IE6 are blissfully unaware of any differences!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem would be, as I see it, that your css wouldn't validate. Other than that I see no reason why not to use this type of platform specific features as they don't cause any harm to users whose browsers don't support the features.

Comment: +1 : stating what I wanted to more eloquently (with the validatity statement)

Answer (score 3):

The advantages are that it's much easier than using corner images or other tricks.  The obvious disadvantage is that your page doesn't render as intended on IE, which is still used by more than half the world's web users.

Overall it's situational; I imagine SO gets a higher than usual proportion of people using Firefox, so the IE issue is not as relevant.  And rounded corners are a minor visual improvement, so if some people see it and some don't, it's not that big a deal.

Comment: The IE issue is always relevant, did you (firefox users) complain when people were using IE only functionality?

Comment: There's a significant difference between "can't even use the page" and "the corners on some boxes have an extra 3 pixels".

Comment: @PintSizedCat: IE's colored scrollbars?

Comment: It always starts with something small. Plus, it's the principal of the thing.

Comment: I don't really see how "support a obsolete browser" is a principle thing. Sounds like hanging on to something that should have been buried a long time ago. IE6, that is.

Comment: In any case, as I said, using non-standard CSS *is* a disadvantage, and it is relevant.  It's just (probably) *less* relevant for SO than it would be for, say, msn.com.

Comment: This is kind of grey.  IE8 and Opera are not "obsolete browsers" - border-radius is not an official recommendation yet.  And text-decoration:blink is a standard, but you shouldn't use it, or IE's colored scrollbars, because they suck.  Rounded corners, on the other hand, rock.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [BeefTurkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697169/using-firefox-only-css-to-round-corners-of-elements/697212#697212).

I might even go further and call it a case of [Progressive Enhancement with CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/progressiveenhancementwithcss). To borrow liberally from [Understanding Progressive Enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement), I'd consider rounded corners to be part of the colorful candy coating around the chocolate-covered peanut.

And eventually CSS3 will be ratified and [border-radius](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius) will be standardized. `-moz`, `-webkit` and `-ms` prefixed styles can be removed and replaced with their standard equivalents. Your CSS will validate and people using browsers that don't support CSS3 will **still** have a completely acceptable experience with people using browsers that do support CSS3 will get an *enhanced* experience.

Alternatively you could continue to use the proprietary CSS in addition to any standards to give an enhanced experience to an even larger audience. It would really depend on how much effort maintaining all that CSS requires and how important you feel the enhanced experience is to your audience.

Answer (score 1):

It works in Firefox and the Webkit-based browsers (notably Safari and Chrome).  There are no alternatives for IE or Opera.

The main reason to use it is when you want to give rounded corners to elements that display on top of patterned or unpredictable backgrounds, which is not possible otherwise.  Normal CSS and images can take care of other situations.

It's also ridiculously easy to implement and surely works for more than half the people on this site.

Answer (score -1):

Pitfalls are of course that it's not supported in other browsers and its not in the W3C specification.

The current implementation is bad (both in firefox and webkit) since they do not share the syntax.

Comment: Border-radius is a W3C spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius

which came directly from these vendor-specific implementations.